# Ubuntu Core backup boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, backup

I would really appreciate your support on the following issue.

We have an IoT device running Ubuntu Core on its SSD drive. Once configured the device is installed along the road to perform some specific task, so it needs to run continuously and it can NOT be assisted by any human support (remote, local and similar stuff, i.e. no keyboard, no usb stick, no live cd, ....). The device is supposed to be 100% autonomous.

We experienced that sometimes the booting procedure hangs up, and the system does not properly start (sometimes read only issue, sometimes other issues..).

We want to increase the robustness of the device, by allowing a backup boot procedure.

So we want to create another boot partition on the same ssd, with exactly the same kernel & distro, which can be used to boot the system in case the "default" boot hangs-up somewhere. Of course, the system needs to understand autonomously if the "default" boot gets an error somewhere.

Shall we need to work on that at MBR/GRUB level? At BIOS level (we are on an Intel architecture)?

Is there someone can please point us on the right direction?

Many thanks for your kind support.